# probability consumes drugs?

Tags: probability

I have a question regarding to a exercise!

Randy is randomly chosen for a drug test. On average 4% of all tested persons are drug users. The used drug test correctly identifies drug users 96% of the time and correctly identifies non-drug users 90% of the time. Assuming Randy tests positive for drugs, calculate the probability that Randy really consumes drugs.

Can help me somebody please?

Greets!

Comment: Who is Hans?$\mbox{}$

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  You'll get a lot more help, and fewer votes to close, if you show that you have made a real effort to solve the problem yourself.  What are your thoughts?  What have you tried?  How far did you get?  Where are you stuck?  This question is likely to be closed if you don't add more context.  Please respond by **editing the question body.**  Many people browsing questions will vote to close without reading the comments.

Comment: Useful **hint**: Make a Two-Way-Table/Frequency-Table. Please show your attempt.

Comment: The first (Hans) revision was much more interesting.

Comment: Provocative title...

Answer (score 2):

I would use the method people here have seen me use repeatedly:

Imagine a population of 10000 people.  4% of them, 400, are drug users and the other 96%, 9600 are not.

The drug test correctly identifies drug-users 96% of the time so it would identify 96% of the 400, 384, as drug-users, the other 400- 384= 16 as non-drug-users.

The drug test correctly identifies non-drug-users 90% of the time so it would identify 90% of the 9600, 8640, as non-drug-users, the other 9600- 8640= 960 as drug-users.

That is, a total of 384+ 960= 1344 people test positive of whom 384 actually are.  If a person test positive the probability they really use drugs is 384/1344=0.2857 or about 28.6%.

Comment: +1.  I always like this method for introducing the right kind of reasoning...

Answer (score 0):

First, compute 
$$
P(test \ positive) = P(test \ positive|real \ positive)P(real \ positive) + P(test \ positive|real \ negative)P(real \ negative) = 0.96 \times 0.04 + 0.1 \times 0.96 
$$
Now, use Bayes formula:
$$
P(real \ positive|test \ positive) = \frac{P(test \ positive|real \ positive) P(real \ positive)}{P(test \ positive)}
$$